# Upload Multiple Resized Images Using Javascript (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, upload

I have put together this code from different sources, it works if I remove the resizing code. I am able to upload multiple files using the for loop as it is, but unable to grasp the resizing technique. I suspect there is something to do with the file reader. How to fix the resizing part? Thanks.

Here is the JavaScript part:

```
function fileToDataUri(field) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
      resolve(reader.result);
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(field);
  });
}       

function resizeImage(imgToResize, resizingFactor = 0.3) {
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const originalWidth = imgToResize.width;
  const originalHeight = imgToResize.height;
  const canvasWidth = originalWidth * resizingFactor;
  const canvasHeight = originalHeight * resizingFactor;
  canvas.width = canvasWidth;
  canvas.height = canvasHeight;
  context.drawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, originalWidth * resizingFactor, originalHeight * resizingFactor );
  return canvas.toDataURL();
}

function uploadImage() {

    var input_files = document.getElementById('input_images');
    var form = new FormData();

    for (i = 0; i < input_files.files.length; i++) {

        // RESIZE
        var file = input_files.files[i];

        var original_image = new Image();
        original_image.src = fileToDataUri(file);

        var resized_image = new Image();
        resized_image.src = resizeImage(original_image);

        // UPLOAD 
        form.append("image", resized_image);

        var settings = {
            "url": "my-api-url",
            "method": "POST",
            "timeout": 0,
            "processData": false,
            "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
            "contentType": false,
            "data": form
        };

        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
            //console.log(response);
            var jx = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(jx.data.url);
            document.getElementById("uploaded_images").innerHTML = document.getElementById("uploaded_images").innerHTML + "<br><div><img src='" + jx.data.url + "'> &nbsp; " + jx.data.url + "</div>";
        });

    }
}
```

The HTML part:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" name="input_images" id="input_images" multiple> 
<input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="uploadImage();">
<div id="uploaded_images"></div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is working fine for me. Everything has been converted from jQuery to JavaScript.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload Images</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        .uploaded {
            border:1px solid #CCC;
            margin:5px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>

    function getFilesReady(e) {
        var preview_images = document.getElementById("preview_images");
        if (e.target.files) {
            var filesAmount = e.target.files.length;
            for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    let html = document.querySelector("body").innerHTML;
                    let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html");
                    let images = doc.querySelectorAll("img");
                    let image = images[images.length-1];
                    image.setAttribute("src", event.target.result);
                    preview_images.appendChild(image);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[i]);
            }
        }
    }
     
    function getResizedBlob(e,file) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = e.target.result;
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        var MAX_WIDTH = 1000;
        var MAX_HEIGHT = 1000;
        var width = img.width;
        var height = img.height;
        if (width > height) {
            if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                width = MAX_WIDTH;
            }
        } else {
            if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                height = MAX_HEIGHT;
            }
        }
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
        var dataurl = canvas.toDataURL(file.type);
        var arr = dataurl.split(','), mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
            bstr = atob(arr[1]), n = bstr.length, u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
        while(n--){
            u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
        }
        return new Blob([u8arr], {type:mime});
    }
    
    
    var upload_counter = 0;
    var total_files;
    function multipleImageUpload() {
        document.getElementById("image_loader").innerHTML = "<img src='https://i.ibb.co/NsY3nDw/loader-on.gif'>";
        var files_to_upload = document.getElementById('selected_files').files;
        total_files = files_to_upload.length;
        for (i = 0; i < total_files; i++) {
            var file = files_to_upload[i];
            //console.log(file);
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = async function(e) {
                const form = new FormData();
                form.append("image", getResizedBlob(e,file));
                try {
                    const response = await fetch('imgbb-api-url',{
                        method:'POST',
                        body:form
                    });
                    const result = await response.json();
                    upload_counter++;
                    var uploaded_images = document.getElementById("uploaded_images");
                    uploaded_images.innerHTML = uploaded_images.innerHTML + "<a target='_blank' href='" + result.data.url + "'><img src='" + result.data.thumb.url + "' class='uploaded'></a>";
                    console.log(upload_counter + " ---- " + result.data.url);
                    
                } catch(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
        
        // keep checking after 2 seconds to see if all the files are uploaded
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            if (upload_counter == total_files) {
                console.log("last message after all the uploads");
                document.getElementById("image_loader").innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById("selected_files").value = "";
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input id="selected_files" name="selected_files" type="file" class="selected_files" accept="image/*" onchange="getFilesReady(event);" multiple><br>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="Upload"  onclick="multipleImageUpload()"> 
        <span id="image_loader"></span>
    </div>
    <form method="post">
        <div id="uploaded_images"></div>
    </form>
    
    <div id="preview_images" style="display:none;"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/64DYhjZ/dummy.gif"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I should have updated the original question rather than posting the answer. Just the lack of StackOverflow experience :(